# jquery closest dl element

Tags: jquery, css-selectors, closest

HTML:

```
<dl id="feature-list">
    <dt id="basic" class="category-name">
    <dd id="basic-toggle" class="category-recepient">
        <div class="feature">
            <div class="feature-content">
            <input id="checkbox1" type="checkbox">
        </div>
        </div>
    </dd>
    <dt id="options" class="category-name">
    <dd id="options-toggle" class="category-recepient">
        <div class="feature">
            <div class="feature-content">
            <input id="checkbox2" type="checkbox">
        </div>
        </div>
    </dd>
</dl>
```

JQUERY

```
$('input').change(function () {
    var value = $(this).closest("dt");
    //do something with value.id
});
```

`$(this).closest("dt")` returns the checkbox instead of `<dt id="(category)" class="category-name">`

I tried `$(this).closest(.category-name)`, `$(this).closest("dt").find(.category-name)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
$(this).parents('dd:first').prev('dt'); // or prev('.category-name')
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/fJkUq/

You also need to close your `<dt>` tags, they should not be containing the `<dd>`, but adjacent to them.

Comment: Was just about to finish my answer. Your answer confused me because it is almost identical to what I was going to post.

Comment: @Kerry: With the `<dt>` note and all? :)

Comment: Indeed! I didn't have jsfiddle link though. Kudos ;)

Answer (score 4):

`<dt>` is not an ancestor of `<dd>` , so closest() will never find it.